# How to configure Linux to close the connection if Send-Q is never sent?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, tcp, netstat

There is a TCP client-server connection. The application on the server is sending data regularly. Client machine is then reset physically. Netstat shows Send-Q on the server is filling up, the connection is in the ESTABLISHED state. How to make it disconnect?

The packets are being added to the Send-Q, obviously nothing is sent. The connection closes only after about 5 minutes.

I'd like to set a timeout so if there aren't any packets leaving the Send-Q then close that connection. How to do that?